# ServiceStack razor - redirect from a service with a default view causes exception

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am trying to item-level security.  I have a service like the following:

```
[DefaultView("Customer")]
public class CustomerService : MyServiceBase
{
    public object Get(CustomerRequest request)
    {
         if (UserIsAuthorizedForCustomer(request.Id))
         {
             return new CustomerResponse { Customer = GetCustomer(request.Id) };
         }
         else
         {
             return this.Redirect("/AccessDenied.htm");
         }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when the auth check fails and the service returns the redirect response, it seems like the razor page is still being executed, but with a null Model resulting in a NullReferenceException.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your implementation of `Redirect` does, but the normal way to redirect to an error page is to just throw an exception which follows the redirection rules setup in your AppHost. e.g:

```
if (!UserIsAuthorizedForCustomer(request.Id))
    throw new UnauthorizedException("Not Authorized");
```

In your AppHost you can specify different redirection pages for different error codes, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    CustomHttpHandlers = {
        { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound") },
        { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/login") },
    }
});
```

Or if you only want 1 page you can specify a fallback for unhandled errors:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler = new RazorHandler("/error")
});
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I had forgotten about the CustomHttpHandlers option.  Thank you!